# Why is git submodule update failing?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have the following  `.gitmodules` file:

```
[submodule "web/blog"]
    path = web/blog
    url = git://amygdala.servebeer.com:lucky_blog.git

[submodule "web/old"]
    path = web/old
    url = git://amygdala.servebeer.com:old_lucky.git
```

When I clone the repo and run `git submodule init && git submodule update` (or `git submodule init --update`) I get the following error:

```
Cloning into web/blog...
fatal: Unable to look up  (port 9418) (Name or service not known)
Clone of 'git://amygdala.servebeer.com:lucky_blog.git' into submodule path 'web/blog' failed
```

I observe three things which cause some concern:

1. The second `.gitmodules` entry (web/old) is cloned just fine, with no issues.
2. There appears to be an extra space in the error message, where I think git would normally list the hostname it fails to look up (right before the port number listing in the error listed above).
3. `git clone git://amygdala.servebeer.com:lucky_blog.git` works just fine.

What is wrong with this repo? Is this an error with git or did I screw something up when setting up the repo?

*Edit* Here's my git config for reference:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@amygdala.servebeer.com:luckybead.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[submodule "web/blog"]
    url = git://amygdala.servebeer.com:lucky_blog.git
[submodule "web/old"]
    url = git://amygdala.servebeer.com:old_lucky.git
```

Comment: Did you try to: remove the first block. Duplicate the second block, and replace `old` by `blog` in that second block? (both inverting the order, and making sure there isn't any kind of special character that might have caused the bug in the original first block)

Comment: Can you show your submodules related stuff from `.git/config`?

Comment: VonC: the duplication didn't seem to work.

dmedvinsky: added the config for your reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have the [format of your git URLs](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-clone.html#URLS) slightly wrong - you should separate the host from the path with `/` rather than `:`.  Try changing the URLs to:

```
git://amygdala.servebeer.com/lucky_blog.git
git://amygdala.servebeer.com/old_lucky.git
```

You will not only need to commit those changes to `.gitmodules`, but also change the config with:

```
$ git config submodule.web/blog.url git://amygdala.servebeer.com/lucky_blog.git
$ git config submodule.web/old.url git://amygdala.servebeer.com/old_blog.git
```

... and to make sure that the submodules are re-cloned, remove them and try the `git submodule update` again.